# custom php.ini for domain

Tags: php, apache, php-ini

I have global php.ini file located in `/usr/local/lib` folder. The custom php.ini file is in `/home/petstail/public_html/` folder.

This is how my phpinfo() look like.

[image]

I am still loading global php.ini file.
How to change configuration file path, and run custom php.ini file.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might be able to do it via `.htaccess` by setting an environment variable (if Apache is running mod_php):

`SetEnv PHPRC /home/petstail/public_html/php.ini`

However, your php.ini file **should not** be in the document root (where it's publicly accessible) ... at the very least store it in a directory protected with another `.htaccess` defining `Deny from all`.

OR you could deny access to `php.ini` using the following.

```
<FilesMatch "php.ini">
    deny from all
    allow from 127.0.0.1
<FilesMatch>
```

Comment: Still, it's loading global php.ini

Comment: Apache might not be running `mod_php` - normally you'd set it from within Apache `httpd.conf` or `httpd-vhosts.conf` (with `PHPIniDir`) however, the odds on the host allowing you to do that (unless you're on dedicated hosting) are slim to none. Why exactly do you need to define a custom php.ini? Are there variables you need to set that can't be done at runtime with `ini_set` ?

Comment: I have defined include_path for website itself. And I have production and development websites on same server. I can not use each others include path. That's the reason.

Comment: Yes - but you can set the include path itself via `ini_set('include_path', '/path/to/include/dir');` if you can pick up whether you're running on a dev or live environment you can set the include path relevant to where the code is running in a config file or similar?

Comment: I didn't try it with that. need to check first. thanks.

Comment: In that case, I need to change it with every subdomain. and everytime I need to modify those files after uploading content from development to production. I am not using any framework here. so, it's gonna be tough to manage code.

Comment: If you can define sub-domains, then you could try adding `php_value include_path /path/to/include/dir` to your `<VirtualHost>` directive in `httpd-hosts.conf` or you might even get away with `PHPIniDir /path/to/php.ini` and be able to redefine the path to the php.ini file itself.

Answer (score 0):

Depending on your php version you should refer the the php documentation to see if INI settings are on.

See here:
http://www.php.net/manual/en/configuration.file.per-user.php

Comment: I am using php 5.4.25

Comment: As they have changed the external ini file `.user.ini`but there is limit changeables that you can change i would refer to this [link](http://www.php.net/manual/en/ini.list.php)

Comment: FYI `sendmail_path` can *not* be set from `.user.ini` files, as it's a `PHP_INI_SYSTEM` setting. In other words: You can not switch mailers for some proxy catcher like mailhog in local environments.